# what is http request.writer[] ? if i redirect some data to this object, where does this go?

Tags: java, http, groovy, request

I have the following piece of groovy code :

```
def Data  = request.params.ReportData[];
request.writer[] << reportData;
```

The code in the file ends after this. I am trying to understand this file better an d was wondering what the request.writer[] object is ? where is the data redirected to ? how can I print this data ?

Comment: Most likely those two places have `.getAt(Collection)` overridden and do something special (Groovy itself will give you an empty list here).  So without context, what libraries etc you use here, it's very hard to guess what is happening here.

Comment: the only thing I don't understand here is why no compilation error is thrown. The code it totally wrong with empty subscript operation: `writer[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be a IBM WebSphere Smash specific data structure. I didnot have access to this code. Closing the question